# tabBar BACK button will not work on tableView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uibutton, segue

I have developed a storyboard iPhone app and I have one issue that I just can't resolve. I've looked here for answers and googled but still can't find a remedy, thanks in advance for any help or answers.

I have a mainViewController that segues to a viewController with a tableView and single cell. The table displays a list of products populated from an array and navigates to a detailViewController that displays images from another array. The tableView and detail controller are working fine. My issue is the back button on my productViewController. When you first arrive at the product table the back button returns you to the mainViewController, after navigating to the detailViewController the back button return you to the last view and not to the MainViewController. I've tried using segues, IBAction codes etc. When I connect a segue in the storyboard it simply crashes the app. I've used the exact same segues on other viewControllers in the same app and they perform as expected. The problem is only on this one viewController.

```
#import "productViewController.h"
#import "detailViewController.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface productViewController ()

{
    int _selectedRowNum;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic)NSString *list;

@end


@implementation productViewController

@synthesize images;
@synthesize details;
@synthesize detailTableView;



- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
  }

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


   self.productTableView.delegate = self;
   self.productTableView.dataSource = self;


   images = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:
               @"flor-sil",
               @"flor-shield",
               @"flor-finish",
               @"flor-finish-lg",
               @"flor-guard",
               @"flor-color",
               @"pc-5614",
               @"rsg",
               @"flor-cure",
               @"flor-clean",  nil];

    details = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:
                @"sil-detail",
                @"flor-shield-detail",
                @"finish-detail",
                @"finish_lg-detail",
                @"ex-detail",
                @"color-detail",
                @"pc-5614-detail",
                @"rsg-detail",
                @"flor-cure-detail",
                @"flor-clean-detail",   nil];

    }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

This is the next section in the same viewController;

```
#pragma mark - Table View Delegate 

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return images.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath

        {
            static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"BasicCell";
            UITableViewCell *myCell = [tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


        long row = indexPath.row;

        myCell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: images[row]];


            return myCell;
        }



-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath

{
   _selectedRowNum = indexPath.row;

   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailSegue" sender:self];

}


-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender

  {

        detailViewController *detailVC = segue.destinationViewController;

        detailVC.imgName = details [_selectedRowNum];

        NSLog(@"Segue");
    }

- (IBAction)back:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

@end
```

Other code I've tried;

```
-(IBAction) back: (id)sender {
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Using this code when replacing "self dismissViewController" does nothing. No response.